# No definition found for 'myMethod' in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

No definition found for 'myMethod' in VS Code

I have some angular projects. After I import one project into VS Code, I can use 'F12' to go to definition.
But when I import one other project, I could't use this feature in VS Code and it tells me '**No definition found for 'myMethod'**'.`myMethod` is already defined in the `ts` file. In this project, I can't use the feature to go to definition of anything.

I don't know why it doesn't work in this special project.
Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Please share some example code or a small example project

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to restart vscode

Use `ctrl` in windows or `cmd` in Mac and `click` the method to head to it

Comment: update to latest vs code version and make sure these methods are exposed to the app